# What will be the time complexity given algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What will be the time complexity(big O notation) of the following algorithm

```
for(int i=3 ; i<n/3; i+=3){
       for(int j=2 ; j<n/2; j+=2){
           //O(1) operation
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think the answer is?  How are you attempting to find out?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your reasoning?  How did you find the answer "O(n)"?  Take into account the complexity of the inner loop and the complexity of the outer loop.

Comment: @DrewDormann  I mean O(n^2) not O(n)

Answer (score 2):

by approximation:

```java
for(int i=3 ; i<n/3; i+=3){ //         ( n/3 - 3 ) / 3 = n/9 - 1 times
       for(int j=2 ; j<n/2; j+=2){ //  ( n/2 - 2 ) / 2 = n/4 - 1 times
           //O(1) operation
        }
    }
```

so the final answer is: `(n/9 - 1)*(n/4 - 1)*O(1) = (n^2 / 36 - ...)*O(1) ≈ O(n^2)`